# Axios GET returns a string which is an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, object, axios

I have built a function that sends an `axios` Request. I use `typescript` and don't want to use `any` as the return data types of the function and the `axios` request itself.

The problem is, however, that the object that comes back contains the params id, which in turn is an object.
Honestly, I have never seen such an object. I do not even know what kind of an object that is. Maybe it is some basic stuff which I never heard about. It is pretty difficult to make a good google search regarding that.

I want to create an `typescript interface` out of it. I do not even have a good idea to start.

Would appreciate any help

this is a small part of the return object:

```
 {
          data{
           '12345': { // params.id --> causing my poblem
                   address: {
             ...,
        }}}
    }
```

Thats my function

```
async function getData (): Promise<IReturnData[]> {
const {data} = await axios.get<IReturnData>(`....${id}`) // in our case 12345
return Object.entries(data.data)[0];

}
```

How should I build IReturnData ?

```
    export interface IReturnData {
      data {
          string: { adress: Adress......
    }}}
   

    or 
    export interface IReturnData {
      data  {
          "1234 but that will change on every request": {
             adress: Adress......
     }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is using [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

But it's not perfect, see the example below, or [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZx8gbwFgAoZc5BAewFdwoBPALmRzClAHMBuUgX1KlQkWIhQBZBuKroIAG0KkKyANoBrCM1bsuAXRYYsuHLxICSpaiDbJOVGQFEAHnAC2ABzkQWk6bIUAvIpkFABEAIwATADMACwArKEsxCHK5NR07FqhAOLQrnAgDKFKFObmllTWYMgARnDozm6e3si+MvLIQQTIAPS9yADKDXIMyGAAFsD4cHI4VMgA7lRQajgANHU0NQCSyOhVAOQ1k6Bq4xPQKNPIcEtwY2ALcsCuwDXv4wtVKBoMpeQIjEEklgmkKBl6Nk8lACkUSqlkHx1gDkKFgfEAGyglLg9K0KEsXL5QrFVHlIA)...

```
interface MyModel {
    [key: string]: Address;
}

const goodExample: MyModel = {
    "12345": {
        country: "Germany"
    }
}

const badExample: MyModel = { // Sadly this also works, but I don't think there is a way to limit it to one key
    "12345": {
        country: "Germany"
    },
    "23456": {
        country: "Germany"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. thx. The main issue is, that "1234" is not fixed. It changes from request to request

Comment: @maxfromgermany in the typings above it's not fixed either. `MyModel` will accept `"12345"`, `"abc"`, ... Or did I not understand you correctly?